# Incorrect version of node.js and npm during gulp plugins installation in visual studio

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, npm, gulp

When I open my project downloaded from git in VS2015, it runs `npm install` to install my Gulp plugins. But the point is that VS using old versions of node.js and npm:

> npm WARN engine gulp-autoprefixer@3.1.0: wanted: {"node":">=0.12.0"}
>   (current: {"node":"v0.10.31","npm":"1.4.9"})

So it causes some errors with the project. How to update them inside VS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're sure there are actual errors and not just warnings, you'll want to update NPM and nodejs.

Installation Steps:

1. Download the Windows installer from the [Nodes.js® website](http://www.nodejs.org/).
2. Run the installer (the .msi file you downloaded in the previous step.)
3. Follow the prompts in the installer (Accept the license agreement, click the NEXT button a bunch of times and accept the default installation settings).
   installer
4. Restart your computer. You won’t be able to run Node.js® until you restart your computer.

Note: If node or NPM already exists, this will overwrite the files and dispose of old, unnecessary files.

Reference: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/install-node-js-npm-windows